# How to send Cookie with HttpGet Url?

Tags: android, cookies, xml-parsing, apache-commons-httpclient

I am trying to send **Cookie** with **HttpGet Url**. which receive from my *service(call by HttpGet)*, for Authentication. I send it with Url but every time get error message.

like:"**User must be Authentificated**".

I get following **error**.

```
05-15 10:28:17.623: I/System.out(18393): <root>
05-15 10:28:17.623: I/System.out(18393): <status>0</status>
05-15 10:28:17.623: I/System.out(18393): <error>User must be Authentificated</error>
05-15 10:28:17.623: I/System.out(18393): </root>
05-15 10:28:17.623: I/System.out(18393): response =: org.apache.harmony.xml.dom.DocumentImpl@41bff838
05-15 10:28:17.623: I/System.out(18393): sts value =: 0
05-15 10:28:17.623: I/System.out(18393): print customer actived bid api sts values 1 che...
```

**Screenshot of my demo** with error message.
[image]

Anyone have an Idea to resolve this problem...

Comment: Can you add the code? Sidenote: You know it's *cancel* instead of *cencel* right?

Answer (score 0):

The server will send you a `Set-Cookie` header which you will have to use to get the cookie and send it in all other requests. Here is a small demonstration.

```
String cookie;
private static String cookieHeader = "Cookie";
private static String Header_SetCookie = "Set-Cookie";

public HttpResponse get(String url) {
    HttpGet getMethod = new HttpGet(url);
    DefaultHttpClient hc = new DefaultHttpClient();
    if(cookie!=null) {
        getMethod.addHeader(cookieHeader, cookie);
    }
    HttpResponse response = hc.execute(getMethod);
    Header[] headers = response.getAllHeaders();
    for (int i = 0; i < headers.length; i++) {
        Header h = headers[i];
        if(h.getName().equals(Header_SetCookie)){
            cookie = h.getValue();
        }
    }
    return response;
}
```